# Can @RequestBody pass null value inside?

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have a post method provide:

```
    @PostMapping("/products")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> newProduct(@RequestBody ProductDto newProduct) {
        try {
            if (newProduct == null) {
                return new ResponseEntity<>(ApiResponseMessage.getGenericApiResponse(Boolean.FALSE, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
                        MessageConstant.EMPTY_REQUEST_BODY_MSG), new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            }

            Product createProduct = productService.createProduct(newProduct);
            if (createProduct != null) {
                return new ResponseEntity<>(createProduct, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.CREATED);
            } else {
                return new ResponseEntity<>(ApiResponseMessage.getGenericApiResponse(Boolean.FALSE, HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY,
                        MessageConstant.PRODUCT_CAN_NOT_CREATED_MSG), new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error(MessageConstant.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR_MSG + ex.getMessage());
            return new ResponseEntity<>(ApiResponseMessage.getInternalServerError(), new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
```

I think this check is irrelevant and we don't need it. Because it's not possible to pass the null value inside the method.

```
if (newProduct == null) {
   return new ResponseEntity<> (ApiResponseMessage.getGenericApiResponse(Boolean.FALSE, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
                                MessageConstant.EMPTY_REQUEST_BODY_MSG), new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Sorry but are you asking if it works? Have you not used it yourself? Are you getting an error? Is something not working as intended? I don't understand what you are actually asking here. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @TheGrandJ I update the question. Does it make sense now?

Comment: yes it does but now it seems this question might be more suited on [codereview.se]. Since it works but you are actually asking for best practice/improvement. (I'm sorry if I am incorrect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using just `@RequestBody`, then get below exception in client tool such as postman or other if you don't pass `ProductDto`, So checking NULL is not required.

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-11-17T06:19:18.268+00:00",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/products"
}
```

Comment: That is if the request body is 0 bytes, but what happens if the request is content type `application/json` and the request body is the 4-letter text `null`?

Comment: if the both condition are met, i.e. ```application/json``` and ```null``` then the same error. i just tested.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation and this is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try @Valid, it might be better